# How can I can make my android app check user's typing speed in background?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I am trying to make an app that can check the typing speed of the user in the background and after that, at the end of the day, it will show a notification of average typing speed. But I am confused about how to make it detect typing speed continuously in the background. BTW I just started with android and this came into my mind.

Comment: you need to use a background task or thread task. the first, you need to get the permission, when you have the permission, you must dispatch